# Azure funtions context.log doesnt works inside a function callback

Tags: node.js, azure-functions

I am trying to debug an Azure function written in nodejs. The problem is, context.log works in some cases, but never got worked within a call back function. I am providing some sample code for the same:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const config =
{
    host: 'xxxx.mysql.database.azure.com',
    user: 'xxxx@xxxx',
    password: 'xxxxx',
    database: 'xxxxx',
    port: 3306,
    ssl: true
};

let mysql_pool = new mysql.createPool(config);

module.exports = async function (context, mySbMsg) {
    // Following statement works
    context.log('JavaScript ServiceBus queue trigger function processed message', mySbMsg);



    mysql_pool.getConnection( (err, db_connection)=> {
                                    if (err) {
                                        if (db_connection) db_connection.release();
                                    }else{
                                        // Following statement doesn't works
                                        context.log("Connection established.");
                                        processData(db_connection);
                                    }
    })

    func1();
    function func1(){
        // Following statement works
        context.log('from func1');
    }

};
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be mixing async and callbacks, your function execution is returning before your callback gets called. If you remove the `async` keyword from the function definition and add a `context.done` call after your the last statement in your else block you should see the desired result. Otherwise should change your code to use and return promises so that the execution is awaitable.